# Accessing a form inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, iframe

I'm trying to load a form inside of an iFrame and then login to it using JavaScript, the two for loops arefor selecting the login fields.  What I'm having problems with accessing the form element in the DOM tree.  The line `var form = doc.forms[0];` isn't giving me any issues but when I try to use functions like `form.action` it's saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'action' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

```
<HTML>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body> 
        <iframe height="300px" id="carrierPage" name="carrierPage" src="" width="100%"></iframe>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function autoLogin(username, password, url){
                var iframe = document.getElementById("carrierPage");;
                iframe.src = url;
                var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
                var form = doc.forms[0];
                form.action = url;
                form.target = "carrierPage";
                for(var i = 0; i < form.length; i++)
                    if(form.elements[i].type == "text"){
                        form.elements[i].value = username;
                        i = form.length + 1;
                    }
                for(var i = 0; i < form.length; i++)
                    if(form.elements[i].type == "password"){
                        form.elements[i].value = password;
                        i = form.length + 1;
                    } 
                form.submit();  */  
            }

            autoLogin("someUserName", "somePassword", "https://someURL.com/login");         
            </script>
        </body>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: And the protocol, domain and port is the same in the iframe as in the parent page, otherwise you're violating the same origin policy

Comment: var doc = iframe.contentDocument;

Comment: Assuming no origin policy issue another possibility can be cross-browser issue of contentWindow vs. contentDocument.

Comment: Guys, "`doc.forms[0]; isn't giving me any issues`" tells the reference to to the `iframe.document` is OK... @paulp `doc.forms[0]` can still be `undefined`, you have to wait untill the `iframe` will be fully loaded, before referring to elements within it.

Comment: @Teemu how do I make sure that the iFrame is loaded beforehand without using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Though you don't have any problems when referring to `doc.forms[0]`, `doc.forms[0]` still might be `undefined`. Before referring to an element within `iframe`, you've to wait untill the content of the new page has been loaded to the `iframe`. You can do something like this:

```
function autoLogin(username, password, url){
    var iframe = document.getElementById('carrierPage');
    iframe.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        var form = doc.forms[0];
            ...
        form.submit();
    });
    iframe.src = url;
}
```

Comment: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.someURL.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "file", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Comment: @paulp Actually it's odd, that you stated "`form = doc.forms[0]; isn't giving me any issues`", if you get this particular error message now when using the fixed code...?